# Group by not working in GCP but Same query execute in Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database

This query is not execute in GCP using Php. Same query execute in Local Server. 
Please suggest me how to get result?

```
select sum(decl_count) as decl_count , sum(counts) as total  
    FROM 
        (select dates,max(version) as version, counts, decl_count 
    FROM
        (select version, count(declaration) as counts,
        count(case when declaration=1 then 1 else null end) as decl_count, 
        date(productiondate) as dates FROM table_name
        WHERE  edition='abc' and MONTH(productiondate) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
        AND YEAR(productiondate) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())  
        GROUP BY version, date(productiondate) 
        ORDER BY version DESC ) AS temp 
        GROUP BY dates   ORDER BY dates DESC) as temp2
```

Comment: You are grouping by one column which means you may only select that column or aggregates of other columns.  Your observations are due to one MySQL being in only full group by mode and the other one with this mode turned off.

Comment: Put some effort into formatting the query so it makes some sense.